# VSCode C/C++ extension not finding (some of?) libc

Tags: visual-studio-code

The C/C++ VSCode extension is displaying behavior that looks to me something like dementia; random typedefs and other elements of the C standard library are not found at seemingly random times.

In spite of including headers from the standard library like <stdbool.h> and <stdint.h> in a given file, bool and uint8_t type declarations are getting red squiggly underscores and generic "identifier [TYPE] is undefined" errors.

This seems to only affect *some* of the files in my project. Within one of the problematic files, uint16_t is accepted without a problem, but uint8_t is not found (<stdint.h> is included, obviously). stderr is also not found on one file that does include <stdio.h>, and contains calls to fprintf.

The only change I made to the extension configuration was to add an include path for SDL2. I've tried restarting VSCode, restarting my computer, uninstalling and reinstalling the C/C++ extension, and resetting the IntelliSense database for that extension. My project builds and runs with no issues.

I'm using the latest version of VSCode on MacOS, with no special configuration beyond keyboard shortcuts. The problem only started recently.

Here's the current extension configuration. This is as it came out of the box, except for the extra include path. The behavior remained the same when that extra path was excluded.

```
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Mac",
            "includePath": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/**",
                "/opt/homebrew/include/"
            ],
            "defines": [],
            "macFrameworkPath": [
                "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks"
            ],
            "compilerPath": "/usr/bin/gcc",
            "cStandard": "c99",
            "cppStandard": "c++17",
            "intelliSenseMode": "macos-gcc-arm64"
        }
    ],
    "version": 4
}
```

Am I missing something? I feel crazy. Any tips much appreciated!

[image: weird inconsistencies]

Comment: How did you configure the plugin? What does you `c_cpp_properties.json` file look like?

Comment: I reinstalled, so it's out of the box:

```
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Mac",
            "includePath": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/**"
            ],
            "defines": [],
            "macFrameworkPath": [
                "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks"
            ],
            "compilerPath": "/usr/bin/clang",
            "cStandard": "c17",
            "cppStandard": "c++17",
            "intelliSenseMode": "macos-clang-arm64"
        }
    ],
    "version": 4
}
```

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question to add it. Don't post crucial information (or formatted text) as comments.

Comment: Try Clangd instead of the stock intellisense, seems to be saner in general.

Comment: Thanks @HolyBlackCat, switched to Clangd and I'm happy with it (now that I've turned off the weird "inlay hints" :))